# Why can a simple EventBrite form be embedded for tickets, but not registrations?

Tags: eventbrite

You can [embed a simple form](http://help.eventbrite.com.au/customer/en_au/portal/articles/428387-embed-ticket-form-into-your-website) if you want to sell tickets, but if you want registrations you have to [embed an entire page](http://help.eventbrite.com.au/customer/en_au/portal/articles/426215-embed-registration-form-into-your-website) -- is this determined by EventBrite's business model or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion here, for ticketing or registration -- you can actually use either widget (and the language of the widget will change dynamically depending on what you've selected for the respective event).

It's poor naming on our part, and I can definitely understand why it's confusing.

Feel free to use either widget for ticketing or registration.

Hope that helps!